# How do I design a angularjs calendar that will highlight some of the dates based on database value

Tags: html, angularjs, hibernate

i am designing a leave management tool where in i want to display a calendar that will display some of the dates in some particular color. The date to be highlighted will be taken from a database which will have dates of employee's leave list.I am using angularjs and hibernate for this.Please suggest me methods to go forward.I am still in planning stage .I have come across full-calendar event calendar.Is it the right one to use .Please help

Comment: Check out [ui-calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/), an angularjs integration of full-calendar. Now I'm voting to close this question, as questions asking to recommend a framework aren't [on topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: As for the hibernate part you'll need a Java backend with which your angular app will communicate